# How can I determine who locked a file using SVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We are using SVN server 1.4 (I think) with the clients being either the command line client or TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The command line client shows the lock owner with the command "svn info".

In TortoiseSVN, you can see the lock owner in the "properties" context menu (tab "subversion").

Comment: Sadly, TortoiseSVN tells me **there are no locks** when I look in that properties/subversion page.  But tells me **_I_ have it locked _elsewhere_** when I try to commit the file.  But won't tell me where I locked it. PS: I only ever lock (on purpose) in one Windows directory.  I was hoping to find where the accidental lock took place.

Comment: @JesseChisholm: I don't think Subversion records the working copy that sent the lock. Anyway, if you are certain you do not have outstanding changes, you can just break the lock.

Comment: ultimately, I had to go to every machine that had an SVN sandbox and check to see if an accidental lock was created there `svn status --show updates` until I found the machine that had the unintentional lock.  Then I could release that lock `svn unlock offendingFile` and clear the situation.

Comment: @JesseChisholm: You can break the lock without knowing where it was created; see http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.locking.html#svn.advanced.locking.break-steal . However, don't do this is someone else is really working on the file.

Comment: I thought I had tried **breaking** the lock, via the TortoiseSVN GUI interface. It is good to know the underlying actual commands.  Thanks.

Comment: This is what TortoiseSVN tells me.
Lock owner: <blank>
Lock creation date: <blank>
locked (cleanup requred): no

Nonetheless, when I try to delete the file and commit, it complains that the file is locked in another working copy.

Comment: @Stewart: Hi! That sounds like a new (though related) question :-).

Comment: You can simply try to lock it and it will show an error with the name/id of the person who has already locked it

Answer (score 29):

Use `svn status --show-updates` to discover locks on files. In the following example, Sally discovers there is a lock on raisin.jpg.

```
$ whoami
sally

$ svn status --show-updates
M              23   bar.c
M    O         32   raisin.jpg
       *       72   foo.h
Status against revision:     105
```

Once you know the lock, you can use `svn -info` to discover who set the lock. Notice "Lock Owner" below:

```
$ svn info http://svn.example.com/repos/project/raisin.jpg
Path: raisin.jpg
Name: raisin.jpg
URL: http://svn.example.com/repos/project/raisin.jpg
Repository UUID: edb2f264-5ef2-0310-a47a-87b0ce17a8ec
Revision: 105
Node Kind: file
Last Changed Author: sally
Last Changed Rev: 32
Last Changed Date: 2005-01-25 12:43:04 -0600 (Tue, 25 Jan 2005)
Lock Token: opaquelocktoken:fc2b4dee-98f9-0310-abf3-653ff3226e6b
Lock Owner: harry
Lock Created: 2005-02-16 13:29:18 -0500 (Wed, 16 Feb 2005)
Lock Comment (1 line):
Need to make a quick tweak to this image.
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with later versions of Subversion (e.g. 1.7). When I run svn info, I don't get any information about the lock owner. My solution (which isn't ideal) is to run 'svn status -u --xml filename' and parse the resulting XML.

Comment: Note that you need to pass a URL instead of a local path to `svn info` to get up-to-date locking information.

Comment: re: `need to pass a URL ...` fortunately, just using the local path will tell you the full URL. A little copy/paste ... et viola!

Answer (score 18):

Using the repo-browser feature of TortoiseSVN there is a lock column that shows the user who locked the file.

Right click on the local working copy -> TortoiseSVN-> repo-browser.

Answer (score 9):

Steps to check:

1. Right click on the file/folder on which you want to determine the lock
2. Go to TortoiseSVN Options >> Repo-browser
3. A new window will open and you will get a table view
4. Lock column in the table will show who has the lock

Answer (score 7):

1. Right click the file, select TortoiseSVN, then Check for modifications
2. Click Check repository
3. Scroll to the right to see the Lock column

Comment: Best Answer. Thanks Pradnya & Godsmith.

Answer (score 2):

The following Python script shows all locks and who owns them:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding=UTF-8

# This tool shows who owns the locks in a subversion repository

import sys
import subprocess

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    p = subprocess.Popen(['svn', 'status', '-u', sys.argv[1]], bufsize=1, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
else:
    p = subprocess.Popen(['svn', 'status', '-u'], bufsize=1, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

(so, se) = p.communicate() # start command

lines = [x[21:].strip() for x in so.split('\n') if len(x) > 5 and x[5] == 'K']

for line in lines:
    p = subprocess.Popen(['svn', 'info', line], bufsize=1, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    (so, se) = p.communicate()
    details = [x[12:].strip() for x in so.split('\n') if x.startswith('Lock Owner')][0]
    print '[%s] (%s)' % (details, line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [red book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.advanced.locking.html) section 'Discovering locks'. I believe it contains the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had also this problem concerning the *.aux files.
The solution/problem in my case was that no subdirectories havind a larger depth than 1 are allowed. If you want to use this the subdirectories in the tmp folder must be existing.
e.g. 
--> src--> introduction-->introduction.tex
requires
--> tmp--> introduction-->introduction.aux*
           **********

The underlined directory must be existing.
So in the case of subversion management commit also the directory structure in the tmp folder (without the *.aux) files.